# Datetime SQL command not working

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, datetime

The below code doesn't work because datetime returns a value in this form:
datetime.date(2016, 12, 5). The information in the database was inputed as a datetime so I thought that SQL lite would be able to deal with it.

The only difference is that the date in the table events has hours and minutes hence the LIKE because I am trying to extract all the the events of that day.

## 1st day

```
date1 = (datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(days=1)).date()
rows1 = db.execute ("SELECT * FROM events WHERE date LIKE :date ORDER BY date", date = date1)
```

ERROR

> rows1 = db.execute ("SELECT * FROM events WHERE date LIKE :date ORDER
>   BY date", date = date1) File
>   "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cs50/sql.py", line 41, in execute
>   raise RuntimeError(e) RuntimeError: Don't know how to literal-quote
>   value datetime.date(2016, 12, 5)

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it..

```
date1 = (datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(days=1)).date()
rows1 = db.execute ("SELECT * FROM events WHERE date LIKE :date ORDER BY date", date = str(date1) +'%')
```

In order for like to work you need a %

Comment: What fixed it is stringifying `date1` with `str(date1)` so you're passing in the string `2016-12-06`. The Python SQLite driver was telling you it didn't know how to stringify a date object, you had to do it for it. The `%` is just a wildcard for `LIKE`, now you're passing in `2016-12-06%` which will match any date that starts with `2016-12-06`.